# How to get both resulting text and the replaced items using preg_replace()?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to get both resulting text, and the replaced text using preg_replace() (or any other funstion) in PHP?

```
// Have:
$txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, REPLACE_ME consectetur adipiscing elit.";

// Desired result:
$txt == "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, WAS_REPLACED consectetur adipiscing elit."
$replaced_text == 'REPLACE_ME'
```

The preg_replace() seems to return either replaced parts, or the resulting text. And `${1}` vars seems to be empty after the preg_replace() call;

**EDIT2**: Got some help from outside, here's the final version:

```
$re = "/REPLACE_ME/i";
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, REPLACE_ME consectetur adipiscing elit.";
$subst = "WAS_REPLACED";

$replacements;

$result = preg_replace_callback(
    $re, 
    function ($matches) use(&$replacements, $subst)  {
        $replacements = $matches[0];
        return $subst;
    },
    $str, 1);

echo $result."\n";
echo $replacements;
```

Comment: I'm not php dev, Just trying to make a little mod to my phpBB board.

Comment: Why you used double equal sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(REPLACE_ME)
```

Directly use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/56

```
$re = "/(REPLACE_ME)/im";
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, REPLACE_ME consectetur adipiscing elit.";
$subst = "WAS_REPLACED";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

`$1` or `\1` will contain the replaced text.

EDIT:To get `Replaced content` you can use this.Check the array `$matches`

```
$re = "/(REPLACE_ME)/im";
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, REPLACE_ME consectetur adipiscing elit.";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: `$result` will be modified `$str`. but I still don't have any variable that contains matched text (`REPLACE_ME` in this example; consider pattern to be complicated). it is enough for me to just get the first match too, so you can add `1` as fourth argument.

Comment: sorry, saw it before your edit.. how do I access `$1` on the next line? simple `$r = $1;` gives me error. and `${1}` is empty.

Comment: @flamey check the edited code.Guess you need to use `match`.`$matches` array will contain what you want

Comment: thanks @vks. i guess I'll need to match first then replace. I was thinking I'm missing something, and you could do things as in Perl. I actually did came up with solution with call back (see my edit), but it not a graceful one. Surely it will be easier to first get a match, then replace.

Comment: someone at work explained to me how to do it without `golbal`s. it works with version 5.3+, which is fine. see new edit

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable inside  php delimiters concatenated using `.` operator.

```
$txt = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, REPLACE_ME consectetur adipiscing elit.";
$text_to_replace = 'REPLACE_ME';
$replaced_text = 'WAS_REPLACED';
echo preg_replace('~'.$text_to_replace.'~', $replaced_text, $txt);
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, WAS_REPLACED consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Comment: @flamey see my update. It works for complex patterns also. Post the code the above would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$txt = "Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet REPLACE_ME consectetur adipiscing elit.";
$replaced_text=preg_replace("/REPLACE_ME/","REPLACED_TEXT",$txt);
```

If text is successfully found and replaced,  the given variables will be populated with desired output.

Comment: Yes, but I also need another variable with the matched text (consider $replaced_text to be more complicated regex pattern)

Comment: What you exactly want to say?
Have you tried the above code?